# My variable will not go above 8

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app with a button that every time you press it, the variable has 1 added to it. Then a label is set by the variable. But when the label reaches 8, and you press the button again it crashes with `fatal error: Index out of range`

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

// OUTLETS

@IBOutlet weak var score: UILabel!
@IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
    add()
}


// VARIABLES

var scoreVar = 0
let levelUpAt = [50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000]
var currentLevel = 1
var toAdd = 1

// OVERRIDES

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// FUNCTIONS

// Below code adds to the score

func add() {
    scoreVar += 1 // Adds 1 to scoreVar
    score.text = "\(scoreVar)"; // Updates text to match
    checkForLevelUp(); // Calls the function defined in the next few days ago
}

// Below code checks if the score meets the next level requirements

func checkForLevelUp() {
    if (scoreVar - 1 < levelUpAt[currentLevel - 1]) { // Complicated math-y if statment
        currentLevel += 1
        toAdd += 1
    }
}
}
```

Comment: There are only 8 elements in your array. What do you expect `checkForLevelUp()` to do when `currentLevel` is 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That´s because your variable is 8 and the last index of your array is 7 that´s way you get `fatal error: Index out of range`.

Do your `if-statement` like this instead:

```
if (scoreVar - 1 < levelUpAt[currentLevel - 1] && levelUpAt.indices.contains(currentLevel)) { ... }
```

So you basically check if that index exists in your array too:

```
levelUpAt.indices.contains(currentLevel)
```

Comment: It worked, but now `currentLevel` goes up by 1 every time the button is pressed.

Comment: If you don't want to add +1 when the if is false in checkForLevel up you should move that if logic to add() instead.

Comment: @rawshan-l, `currentLevel` still goes up when it's not supposed to. P.S: add() is now: `func add() {
        if (scoreVar - 1 < levelUpAt[currentLevel - 1] && levelUpAt.indices.contains(currentLevel)) {
            currentLevel += 1
            toAdd += 1
            levelLabel.text = "Level \(currentLevel)"
            scoreVar += toAdd
            score.text = "\(scoreVar)"; 
        } else {
            scoreVar += toAdd 
            score.text = "\(scoreVar)";
        }
    }`

Answer (score 3):

Here: `if levelUpAt[currentLevel - 1]` you are accessing an arrays element. Your array only has 8 elements in it. Once `currentLevel` reaches 8, it will access an element that your array does not hold, therefore it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

There is only 8 elements in your array.

```
let levelUpAt = [50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000]
```

`currentLevel = 9` and you call `checkForLevelUp()`, it is now out of range.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know swift at all, but you are looking up a value in an array of 8 items in checkForLevelUp.

You should add a check that you are within the bounds of the array before looking into it.